# Unable to parse XAML/XML

Tags: c#, xml, xaml, xml-parsing

Can you help me in parsing this XAML?

```
<Deployment xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/client/2007/deployment"
       xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
       EntryPointAssembly="Hello" EntryPointType="Hello.App" RuntimeVersion="4.7.50308.0">
  <Deployment.Parts>
    <AssemblyPart x:Name="Hello" Source="Hello.dll" />
  </Deployment.Parts>
</Deployment>
```

I have tried XmlDocument, XElement, and XamlReader. None is able to load the XAML and fetch me the values.

### Update - Code I tried

```
     var appXaml = ... ; //the XAML string mentioned above
```

XmlDocument:

```
     var x = new XmlDocument();
     x.LoadXml(appXaml);
```

Also,

```
 //I created XSD from the XAML using xsd.exe
 //Placed it in "D:\AppManifest.xsd"
            var n = new XmlDocument();
            var ss = new XmlSchemaSet();
            var s = new XmlSchema() { SourceUri = @"D:\AppManifest.xsd" };
            ss.Add(s);
            ss.Compile();
            n.Schemas.Add(ss);
            n.LoadXml(appXaml);
```

XSD code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xs:schema id="NewDataSet" targetNamespace="http://schemas.microsoft.com/client/2007/deployment" xmlns:mstns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/client/2007/deployment" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/client/2007/deployment" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata" attributeFormDefault="qualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:app1="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
  <xs:element name="Deployment">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="Deployment.Parts" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
              <xs:element name="AssemblyPart" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                <xs:complexType>
                  <xs:attribute name="Name" msdata:Prefix="x" type="xs:string" />
                  <xs:attribute name="Source" form="unqualified" type="xs:string" />
                </xs:complexType>
              </xs:element>
            </xs:sequence>
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
      </xs:sequence>
      <xs:attribute name="EntryPointAssembly" form="unqualified" type="xs:string" />
      <xs:attribute name="EntryPointType" form="unqualified" type="xs:string" />
      <xs:attribute name="RuntimeVersion" form="unqualified" type="xs:string" />
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
  <xs:element name="NewDataSet" msdata:IsDataSet="true" msdata:UseCurrentLocale="true">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
        <xs:element ref="Deployment" />
      </xs:choice>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

XElement:

```
     var z = XElement.Parse(appXaml);
```

XamlReader:

```
var l = XamlReader.Parse(appXaml);
```

Comment: What are you trying to get?

Comment: Where do you want to show/display these values. How do you tried?

Comment: Please show the code you have tried along with the error messages you are getting.

Comment: I want to fetch values for EntryPointAssembly, EntryPointType, RuntimeVersion, and the assemblies mentioned in the AssemblyPart tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that the XAML content that I read from the file contained [BOM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark).

I BOM is stripped out, the XAML code is parsable.

I use Visual Studio 2010. The "Text Visualizer" in debugging mode did not show any sign of BOM (the XAML string is in UTF8). But when I accidently copied the text from the visualizer and pasted in Notepad++, it showed '?' symbol (BOM, in this case.)

Bah. Weird problems in VS.

Answer (score 1):

try passing xml to parse.

```
        XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
        xmlDoc.Load(@"D:\OldDesktop\Try\app.xaml");
        XElement.Parse(xmlDoc.InnerXml);
```

or iterate through xmldoc

```
        XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
        xmlDoc.Load(@"D:\OldDesktop\Try\app.xaml");
        foreach (XmlElement xElement in xmlDoc.DocumentElement)
        {
           //do somthing
        }
```